# Firebase-admin And react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

When I install firebase admin to my project, I get the error that `dns` dependency module is missing. When I add `dns` I get this error below

[image: The error]

What could be causing this error ?

Comment: `dns` is not a dependency of `firebase-admin`. Can you provide more detail, including the exact steps you took?

Comment: I created a new project with react-create-app. That went okay, then I added firebase-admin from npm, after that I got the error saying that dns is not installed , I installed that then I got the error on the photo saying that those other dependencies are not installed `dgram` and `child_process`

Comment: `dns` is not even a dependency of `firebase-admin`, so I'm not sure what is going on. Are you sure you want to even be using `firebase-admin` as opposed to the regular `firebase` node module? `firebase-admin` is for backend server apps.

Comment: Yeap. I wanted to create the ui for the backend app with react. Thats pretty much what I wanted

Comment: How does a backend app have a UI? I'm a bit confused at your use case to be honest.

Separately, I'm really unsure what is causing this error. `dns` is not a dependency of `firebase-admin` so something else must be going on here. Maybe it's an issue with `create-react-app`?

Comment: Heres the thing. The reason I want to use firebase admin is because I want to be able to send notifications to users from the backend. Does it make sense or am I the one who isnt asking the right question

Comment: My main confusion is why React is involved if you are just making a backend app. Do you have two different pieces, a React front-end and a Node.js backend that uses Firebase Admin? If so, that's totally legit. But using firebase-admin in React directly is not a good idea since it will leak your service account to anyone who visits your React app. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah It does. Thanks